# Number data type showing up as # in SQL Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Number data type showing up as # instead of the numbers in SQL Plus.

Please refer to the H_RATE for the issue prevously it was showing up correctly and I have searched the internet and stackoverflow for a simliar issue or answer but none have the same.

Could you help in fixing it so it shows the number instead of #?

[image: screenshot off issue in action]

Comment: How big are the numbers in the column - can you show an example? Have you set a number format - what does `show numformat` display? And have you set a for mat for that column which is inappropriate? Does the display return to normal if you `clear columns`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`#` is displayed if the value can't fit in the column; [from the SQL*Plus documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm#sthref1308):

> If a value cannot fit in the column, SQL*Plus displays pound signs (#) instead of the number.

If it was displaying OK and now isn't, I think you've probably set a column format that is too small for the values you're display, something like `column h_rate format 9999999999`. If you have a 10-digit number that isn't enough, as it needs a character to display a +/- sign.

You can check if that is the case by clearing all column definitions, with [`clear columns`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Your `H_RATE` format may be of smaller digits that of the data:

```
select to_char(123,'99') from dual; --returns ###
```

but do proper formatting some thing greater than the data:

```
select to_char(12345,'99,999') from dual; -- returns 12,345
```

There are various formatting by oracle given [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)