# In the dept table, a column error occurs deptno

Tags: sql, oracle

I do not understand why, instead of the number on the column deptno
Appears #

I am the beginner in this, I am reading a book "The Expert
Oracle
Database Architecture "and I found an example where I need to create this table

Perhaps this book is not for beginners, but I nevertheless began to read it

I use Oracle 12 c r2

Thanks in advance, Peter

```
SQL> create table dept 
  2  ( deptno number(2),
  3  dname varchar2(14),
  4  loc varchar2(13), 
  5  last_mod timestamp with time zone 
  6  default systimestamp 
  7  not null, 
  8  constraint dept_pk primary key(deptno)
  9  ) 
 10  ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into DEPT (DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC)
  2  values(10, 'ACCOUNTING', 'NEW YORK')
  3  ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into DEPT (DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC)
  2  values(20, 'RESEARCH', 'DALLAS');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into DEPT (DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC)
  2  values(30, 'SALES', 'CHICAGO');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into DEPT (DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC)
  2  values(40, 'OPERATIONS', 'BOSTON');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME              LOC       LAST_MOD
---------- ------------------------------ ------------- --------------------------------------------------
########## ACCOUNTING             NEW YORK  28-NOV-18 01.29.06.149308 PM -05:00
########## RESEARCH               DALLAS    28-NOV-18 01.29.20.001800 PM -05:00
########## SALES                  CHICAGO   28-NOV-18 01.29.40.491547 PM -05:00
########## OPERATIONS             BOSTON    28-NOV-18 01.30.10.842314 PM -05:00
```

Comment: Are the department numbers longer than 10 characters? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149371/number-data-type-showing-up-as-in-sql-plus

Comment: maybe you did set some columns formats earlier in your SQLPlus session ?
Can you execute `CLEAR COLUMNS` and rerun the query ? Or just start a new SQLPLUS session